# Sharing a sound in reactnative

Tags: react-native

I've created an app, inside I use react-native-sound to play sounds.
I embedded sounds inside the app. If a user wants to play that sounds, he/she needs to open the app and play it. How can I enable users to share this sound in WhatsApp or other applications? Is there any 3rd party library exist?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook this functionality in their core api to share the content on other applications. [read it here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-share](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share) with [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) to share any file.

`react-native-fetch-blob` making file access and data transfer easier and more efficient for React Native developers.

With `react-native-share` you can share file, checkout the github issue [here](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share/issues/166).